# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf application - how to make several instances of the model attribute

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, modelattribute

I have a Spring Boot + Thymeleaf application and the following working code:

Controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes( {"myBean"} )
public class MyController() {

    @ModelAttribute("myBean") 
    public MyBean getMyBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }

    // multiple requests with "myBean"
    // ...

    @GetMapping("/page1")
    public String page1a(@ModelAttribute MyBean myBean) {
        // some code
        return "page";
    }

    @PostMapping("/page1")
    public String page1b(@ModelAttribute MyBean myBean) {
        // some code
        return "result";
    }
}
```

Thymeleaf page:

```
...
<form action="#" th:action="@{/page1}" th:object="${myBean}" method="post">
    <!-- some fields-->
</form>
...
```

This works fine when I have only 1 page open at a time. I would like to compare the results on several result.html pages though, so I need to be able to work on several pages simultaneously. But I have only 1 instance of "myBean", so the values would be overwritten each time.

Is it possible to have several instances of "myBean"?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could get around this by defining another bean in your session attributes, map myBean to it when needed :

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes( {"myBean", "myResultBean"} )
public class MyController() {

    @ModelAttribute("myBean") 
    public MyBean getMyBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }

    // multiple requests with "myBean"
    // ...

    @GetMapping("/page1")
    public String page1a(@ModelAttribute MyBean myBean) {
        // some code
        return "page";
    }

    @PostMapping("/page1")
    public String page1b(@ModelAttribute MyBean myBean, @ModelAttribute("myResultBean") MyBean myResultBean) {
        // map myBean to myResultBean.
       // some code

        return "result";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Your suggestion is nice but I don't think that it would work in my case. I have multiple requests before the result page and if I haven't reached the result but start a new page simultaneously, I would loose the current data in "myBean".